# AngularJS - Set Default Value if no Value is Selected for Radio Buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have the following group of radio buttons:

```
<div class="checkboxgroup" ng-repeat="p in priorities">
   <input id="radio_{{ $index }}" ng-disabled="disable" type="radio" name="ShipPriority" ng-model="$parent.data.ShipPriority" value="{{ p.value }}" ng-change="UpdateHeader('ShipPriority', {{ p.value }})" />
   <label for="radio_{{ $index }}">{{ p.value }}</label>
</div>
```

The values/labels are the numbers 1-5. As it is set up right now, there is no default value if a value has not previously been selected, simply no radio button is selected. I would like to set the default value equal to 5 if a previous value has not been selected.

Comment: Cant you just set it on the controller?

Comment: You mean the p.value should be 5 if its null?

Comment: @Bardh Lohaj All of the different radio buttons will retain their value but instead of none being selected on null, radio button #5 would be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to only use `ng-checked=""` directive.

So, you add `ng-checked` attribute with an expression like this

```
ng-checked="$index == 1"
```

so, if you want to set the 5th radio button(`$index` = 4) to checked, your radio button in ng-repeat would look like this:

```
<input id="radio_{{ $index }}" ng-disabled="disable" 
    type="radio" name="ShipPriority" 
    ng-model="$parent.data.ShipPriority" value="{{ p.value }}" 
    ng-change="UpdateHeader('ShipPriority', {{ p.value }})"
    ng-checked="$index == 4"
/>
```

---

Another way would be to get the checked value from your priorities array.

So, you set the priority checked value in you controller, something like this:

```
$scope.priorities = [{"value":1},{"value":2, "checked":true}];
```

and than use that value on your view:

```
ng-checked="p.checked"
```

---

Another way would be to use `jQuery`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#radio_4").attr('checked', true);
});
```